# Multiple type user's authority is messy when change user profile with UpdateView - Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, multiple-users

I have three user types in user model(create, query and common), `multiple type` user's authority is messy when I am changing user profile with `UpdateView`, for example, a user who is `admin`, when `admin` clicked a user who is common user, then that user in page is in `common user`'s authority, my `UpdateView` is as below:

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    context_object_name = 'user'
    template_name = 'general/teachers/user_change_form.html'
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

models of user:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="姓名", default="", blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,choices=(("male","男"),("female","女")),
        default="female", verbose_name="性别",
    )
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="所属部门",
    )
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="职位", default="", blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name="手机号", default="", blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, verbose_name="邮箱", default="", blank=True)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='是否是普通用户')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='是否是查询用户')
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='是否是评测人')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="添加时间")
```

forms of user:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'department', 'gender', 'job_title', 'email', 'mobile')
```

Comment: you mean when update any user, your user's `type` is change to `common`? can you upload your user model?

Comment: Hi, I uploaded my user model, thank you so much, when I update any user, my user's type on that page is change to that user's type(common, query or admin), if my original user type is admin, and I update a common user, and search a project on search bar, web will ask me to login in a with admin user type......

Comment: Ok I couldn't see your model right now... and can you upload your `UserForm` either? Oh I now see it. but where's your user type field?

Comment: `is_employee` is common user, `is_teacher` is query use type, and `is_supervisor` is user type for creating

Comment: You mean, I need to put user type field in forms.py?

Comment: If you want to change your user type, yes. But your user type changed now though you don't intend it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173725/discussion-between-seuling-and-begin2pip).

Comment: @Begin2Pip in your `UserForm` in fields there is a `username`, but you don't have a `username` in your `User` model.

Comment: When you update `User` you got redirected to a **seccess** page or the `UserForm` is displayed again?